# Not able to encode , (comma) _(underscore) -(hyphen) using ESAPI encodeforXML method

Tags: java, owasp, encoder, esapi, xmlencoder

In the following code, where I am trying to encode special characters

```
package hello;

//import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI;
import org.owasp.esapi.Encoder;
import org.owasp.esapi.errors.EncodingException;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //System.out.println("Hello Worldadndh");   
        
//      System.out.println("ESAPI.accessacController found: " 
//                + ESAPI.accessController());
                String encodedString = encodeForXML("comma underscore hyphen, _ - & () %");
        System.out.println("The encoded string is "+encodedString); 
        
    
        

    }
    

    
    public static String encodeForXML(String str)
    {
        return ESAPI.encoder().encodeForXML(str);
    }
    
    
    

}
```

The o/p is

```
The encoded string is comma underscore hyphen, _ - &#x26; &#x28;&#x29; &#x25;
```

Are there some settings which is required to encode , _ -? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XML, it is not necessary to encode the underscore character. See https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charencoding.

Only the following characters need to be escaped: https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-escape.